# Remove permanently UIViewController from the stack

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Here is how I remove UIViewControllers which never will be used again in the app.

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1];
```

1. Is this the right way to remove view from the stack ?
2. While running the app with Instruments I notice that the memory is not freed when the app enter the stage where the code above is executed. What is wrong here ?

Comment: Are you removing the right indexes? This would actually remove 0 and 2  without taking into account the reordering after the first remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning your view controllers into a new mutable array you increased their retain count by 1, removing them decreases their retain count by 1 so the net effect is zero. What you want to do is replace the view controllers that are part of the navigation controller after removing them, there by making the navigation controller release your old instances.

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:allViewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: Nope, no effect. The size of memory heap is the same with or without the code you suggest.

Comment: Did you make sure when pushing your viewController on to your navigationController that you released or autoreleased them? UIViewController * controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initMethodUsed]; [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; [controller release];

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new `NSMutableArray` of the `viewControllers` and then removing from the new `NSMutableArray` accomplishes nothing. The `viewControllers` still are retain by the `navigationController`.

Comment: How to remove specific one then ?

Comment: Remove the `viewControllers` from the `navigationController` with one of several methods: `popToRootViewControllerAnimated `, `popToViewController ` or `popViewControllerAnimated `. Also see the answer by @Joel.

Answer (score 0):

you are not actually freeing up the viewControllers. you are just increasing their retain count by +1 and then decreasing by -1.

actually nothing is getting affected by the code you have written to free your viewControllers.

For a NavigationController, you call popToRootViewController to release all other view controllers except the base/root viewcontroller for NavigationController.

Comment: Well, I don't want to remove release all views. Only specific one. How to do that ?